# Line renderer's edge collider sometimes not detecting collisions with object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have edge collider attached to parent line renderer. sometimes the collision won't work and my player pass by it. this specially happens when I move the line renderer and the player just pass through it. Both the line renderer and player has dynamic rigidbody.

Here's my code for line drawer.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LinesDrawer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject linePrefab;
    public LayerMask cantDrawOverLayer;
    int cantDrawOverLayerIndex;

    [Space ( 30f )]
    public Gradient lineColor;
    public float linePointsMinDistance;
    public float lineWidth;

    Line currentLine;

    Camera cam;


    void Start ( ) {
        cam = Camera.main;
        cantDrawOverLayerIndex = LayerMask.NameToLayer ( "CantDrawOver" );
    }

    void Update ( ) {
        if ( Input.GetMouseButtonDown ( 0 ) )
            BeginDraw ( );

        if ( currentLine != null )
            Draw ( );

        if ( Input.GetMouseButtonUp ( 0 ) )
            EndDraw ( );
    }

    // Begin Draw ----------------------------------------------
    void BeginDraw ( ) {
        currentLine = Instantiate ( linePrefab, this.transform ).GetComponent <Line> ( );

        //Set line properties
        currentLine.UsePhysics ( false );
        currentLine.SetLineColor ( lineColor );
        currentLine.SetPointsMinDistance ( linePointsMinDistance );
        currentLine.SetLineWidth ( lineWidth );

    }
    // Draw ----------------------------------------------------
    void Draw ( ) {
        Vector2 mousePosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint ( Input.mousePosition );

        //Check if mousePos hits any collider with layer "CantDrawOver", if true cut the line by calling EndDraw( )
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.CircleCast ( mousePosition, lineWidth / 3f, Vector2.zero, 1f, cantDrawOverLayer );

        if ( hit )
            EndDraw ( );
        else
            currentLine.AddPoint ( mousePosition );
    }
    // End Draw ------------------------------------------------
    void EndDraw ( ) {
        if ( currentLine != null ) {
            if ( currentLine.pointsCount < 2 ) {
                //If line has one point
                Destroy ( currentLine.gameObject );
            } else {
                //Add the line to "CantDrawOver" layer
                currentLine.gameObject.layer = cantDrawOverLayerIndex;

                //Activate Physics on the line
                currentLine.UsePhysics ( true );

                currentLine = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my code for line properties.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Line : MonoBehaviour
{

    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public EdgeCollider2D edgeCollider;
    public Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    [HideInInspector] public List<Vector2> points = new List<Vector2> ( );
    [HideInInspector] public int pointsCount = 0;

    //The minimum distance between line's points.
    private float pointsMinDistance = 0.1f;

    //Circle collider added to each line's point
    private float circleColliderRadius;

    public void AddPoint ( Vector2 newPoint ) {
        //If distance between last point and new point is less than pointsMinDistance do nothing (return)
        if ( pointsCount >= 1 && Vector2.Distance ( newPoint, GetLastPoint ( ) ) < pointsMinDistance )
            return;

        points.Add ( newPoint );
        pointsCount++;

        //Add Circle Collider to the Point
        CircleCollider2D circleCollider = this.gameObject.AddComponent <CircleCollider2D> ( );
        circleCollider.offset = newPoint;
        circleCollider.radius = circleColliderRadius;

        //Line Renderer
        lineRenderer.positionCount = pointsCount;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition ( pointsCount - 1, newPoint );

        //Edge Collider
        //Edge colliders accept only 2 points or more (we can't create an edge with one point :D )
        if ( pointsCount > 1 )
            edgeCollider.points = points.ToArray ( );
    }

    public Vector2 GetLastPoint ( ) {
        return ( Vector2 )lineRenderer.GetPosition ( pointsCount - 1 );
    }

    public void UsePhysics ( bool usePhysics ) {
        // isKinematic = true  means that this rigidbody is not affected by Unity's physics engine
        rigidBody.isKinematic = !usePhysics;
    }

    public void SetLineColor ( Gradient colorGradient ) {
        lineRenderer.colorGradient = colorGradient;
    }

    public void SetPointsMinDistance ( float distance ) {
        pointsMinDistance = distance;
    }

    public void SetLineWidth ( float width ) {
        lineRenderer.startWidth = width;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = width;

        circleColliderRadius = width / 2f;

        edgeCollider.edgeRadius = circleColliderRadius;
    }
}
```

There are circle colliders in the line renderer. The player is not passing when circle colliders are right next to each other but when we drag the line with mouse right away the circle colliders does'nt appear next to each other and player passes through that gap even though there is an edge collider.

Comment: There might be more to your problem, but something that you could quickly try is changing your `Update` to `FixedUpdate`, so that your line generation is synchronized with the physics update.

Comment: @Voidsay Nope it's not working. I think the problem is with the input speed. Maybe unity is not detecting my current mouse position when I drag my mouse with speed. It works all good when I drag the mouse at normal speed.

Comment: Other variants are your players controller moving wrong. There could be a weird interaction in the collision resolution when the player collides with both edge collider and circle collider. The speed/scale can be too big (or small) for the physics settings.
It's hard to test without a good setup.